# I cannot find Google2ubuntu in repositories

Tags: repository, 20.10, voice-recognition

I cannot find the Google2ubuntu app in repositories. I want to use voice commands to operate Ubuntu 20.10. Please help.

Comment: Can you provide a link to this software? Nothing by that name has been packaged by volunteers for 20.10. Everything I can find by that name has been abandoned for many years.

Comment: https://ubunlog.com/google2ubuntu-o-como-controlar-nuestro-ubuntu-mediante-la-voz/

Comment: That link leads you the the .deb file. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can try manual download of [the packages](https://launchpad.net/%7Ebenoitfra/+archive/ubuntu/google2ubuntu/+packages) by commands below:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygobject/python-gi_3.36.0-1_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libf/libffi/libffi7_3.3-4_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/simplejson/python-simplejson_3.16.0-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/pycairo/python-cairo_1.16.2-1_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygobject-2/python-gobject-2_2.28.6-14ubuntu1_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pygtk/python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb

wget https://launchpad.net/~benoitfra/+archive/ubuntu/google2ubuntu/+files/google2ubuntu_1.1.5_all.deb

sudo apt-get install ./python-gi_3.36.0-1_amd64.deb ./libffi7_3.3-4_amd64.deb ./python-simplejson_3.16.0-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb ./python-cairo_1.16.2-1_amd64.deb ./python-gtk2_2.24.0-5.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb ./python-gobject-2_2.28.6-14ubuntu1_amd64.deb ./google2ubuntu_1.1.5_all.deb
```

Then try to launch it by its launchers.

Comment: Thanks Norbert. I will try and let you know